# OpenMP problem with mandelbrot program in c

Tags: c

I have to parallelize using openMP the serial version of a program in C to visualize a Mandelbrot set. I tried to do it but I obtain something really strange.
I know there is something wrong with the declaration of variables into parallel for, but i don't get what's the problem

Do you have any suggestion?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "pngwriter.h"
#include "consts.h"


unsigned long get_time()
{
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    return tp.tv_sec * 1000000 + tp.tv_usec;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    png_data* pPng = png_create(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);

    double x, y, x2, y2, cx, cy;
    cy = MIN_Y;

    double fDeltaX = (MAX_X - MIN_X) / (double)IMAGE_WIDTH;
    double fDeltaY = (MAX_Y - MIN_Y) / (double)IMAGE_HEIGHT;

    long nTotalIterationsCount = 0;
    unsigned long nTimeStart = get_time();

    long i, j, n;

    n = 0;
    int c;

#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp for private( i,c) reduction(+ : cx,cy)
        for (j = 0; j < IMAGE_HEIGHT; j++) {
            cx = MIN_X;

            for (i = 0; i < IMAGE_WIDTH; i++) {
                x = cx;
                y = cy;

                x2 = x * x;
                y2 = y * y;

                for (n = 0; (n < MAX_ITERS) && (x2 + y2 < 4); n++) {
             
                    y = 2 * x * y + cy;
                    x = x2 - y2 + cx;
                    x2 = x * x;
                    y2 = y * y;
                }

                int c = ((long)n * 255) / MAX_ITERS;
                png_plot(pPng, i, j, c, c, c);

                cx += fDeltaX;

                nTotalIterationsCount++;
            }

            cy += fDeltaY;
        }
    }

    unsigned long nTimeEnd = get_time();

  // print benchmark data
  printf("Total time:                 %g millisconds\n",
         (nTimeEnd - nTimeStart) / 1000.0);
  printf("Image size:                 %ld x %ld = %ld Pixels\n",
         (long)IMAGE_WIDTH, (long)IMAGE_HEIGHT,
         (long)(IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT));
  printf("Total number of iterations: %ld\n", nTotalIterationsCount);
  printf("Avg. time per pixel:        %g microseconds\n",
         (nTimeEnd - nTimeStart) / (double)(IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT));
  printf("Avg. time per iteration:    %g microseconds\n",
         (nTimeEnd - nTimeStart) / (double)nTotalIterationsCount);
  printf("Iterations/second:          %g\n",
         nTotalIterationsCount / (double)(nTimeEnd - nTimeStart) * 1e6);
  // assume there are 8 floating point operations per iteration
  printf("MFlop/s:                    %g\n",
         nTotalIterationsCount * 8.0 / (double)(nTimeEnd - nTimeStart));

  png_write(pPng, "mandel.png");
  return 0;
}
```

My output:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzfy1.png)

Comment: Your loop is configured to be executed sequentially, such that `cy` is always updated by a particular step assuming that it's equivalent to `cy = MIN_Y + j * fDeltaY;` -- that's not the case when you split the loop into parallel.  Try using the explicit equation I've shown for `cy` and see if that helps (add that code immediately below `cx = MIN_X;`).  You may also want to declare those as local variables inside the loop.  There's no reason to share them across threads.  If this doesn't help, there may be other contention issues (for example, reentrant calls to `png_plot`).

Comment: I tried with your solution and it seems better, now i'm not getting more rows of the image, but my image becomes more blurred when i increase the threads. With one thread it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out by @paddy you have to calculate `cy` directly using the equation `cy = MIN_Y + j * fDeltaY;` and get rid of many shared variables, as they cause data race. Generally, it is always recommended to define your variables in their minimal required scope. I also suggest to calculate `cx` similarly (`cx = MIN_X + i * fDeltaX;`) it makes possible to use `collapse(2)` clause in your `#pragma omp for` directive and IMO it is also easier to understand your code. You should use reduction in case of `nTotalIterationsCount` only. Please also make sure that `png_plot` is threadsafe. The code should look something like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : nTotalIterationsCount) 
    for (long j = 0; j < IMAGE_HEIGHT; j++) {            
        for (long i = 0; i < IMAGE_WIDTH; i++) {
            double cx = MIN_X + i * fDeltaX;            
            double cy = MIN_Y + j * fDeltaY;
            double x = cx;
            double y = cy;
            double x2 = x * x;
            double y2 = y * y;
            long n;
            for (n=0; (n < MAX_ITERS) && (x2 + y2 < 4); n++) {             
                y = 2 * x * y + cy;
                x = x2 - y2 + cx;
                x2 = x * x;
                y2 = y * y;
            }

            int c = (n * 255) / MAX_ITERS;
            png_plot(pPng, i, j, c, c, c);

            nTotalIterationsCount++;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: I think you should use `nTotalIterationsCount+=n;` instead of `nTotalIterationsCount++;`. Most probably that was your intention.

Comment: Thanks for your help, as I said to @paddy, I'm getting something better but still bad. my image is not splitted in more images like before (I think that could be due to shared variables), but i'm getting a blurred image. With 1 thread it works

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I didn't declare i and j inside the for loop. Works fine when I move the declaration in there.